# Add value from another column in alter table

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I need to add a column in a SQL table. Is it possible to take the new value to be inserted in the new column from a different column?

For example let MyTable be the table to be altered, it has the boolean field `is_ok`, now I want to add the integer field `points`. I want to set the value of the filed `points` for all the previous record to be 1 or 0 based on the `is_ok` field

I tried

```
alter table `MyTable` add `points` integer(16) default `MyTable`.`is_ok`
```

But of course it didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this in MySql?

Comment: I think you need two steps: Add the column, update the table.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are trying **it is not possible.**

Alter the table first and then update the values.

```
alter table `MyTable` add `points` integer(16) default null ;

UPDATE MyTable  SET points = is_ok ;
```

Comment: Aren't we talking about one table here where merely the column gets added? Hence: `update mytable set points = is_ok;`.